# Using Pact.eachLike() when array contents vary for each item

Tags: pact

Hi I have a Consumer test produced using Pact NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/pact

I use the following code to generate a pact.json:

```
provider
    .addInteraction({
        state: 'test',
        uponReceiving: 'a test,
        withRequest: {
          method: 'GET',
          path: '/test'
        },
        willRespondWith: {
            status: 200,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            body: {
                "company": like("My big company"),
                "factories": eachLike({
                    "location": like("Sydney"),
                    "capacity": like(5)
                },{min:1})
            }
        }
    })
    .then(function(){ done(); });
```

It generates the following testconsumer-testprovider.json file:

```
{
  "consumer": {
    "name": "TestConsumer"
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "TestProvider"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "a request for loans",
      "providerState": "broker is logged in, list all loans",
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/test"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/vnd.hal+json"
        },
        "body": {
          "company": "My big company",
          "factories": [
            {
              "location": "Sydney",
              "capacity": 5
            }
          ]
        },
        "matchingRules": {
          "$.headers.Content-Type": {
            "match": "regex",
            "regex": "application\\/.*json.*"
          },
          "$.body.company": {
            "match": "type"
          },
          "$.body.factories": {
            "min": 1
          },
          "$.body.factories[*].*": {
            "match": "type"
          },
          "$.body.factories[*].location": {
            "match": "type"
          },
          "$.body.factories[*].capacity": {
            "match": "type"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "3.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

However when we test against the following provided output we get an error with the geographicCoords because it's an unexpected key/value:

```
{
    "company": "My Company",
    "factories": [
        {
            "location": "Sydney",
            "capacity": 5
        },
        {
            "location": "Sydney",
            "geographicCoords": "-0.145,1.4445",
            "capacity": 5,
        }
    ]
}
```

So is there a was to allow unexpected key/values in arrays because we're only test for required key/values and we don't want out pact tests to fail in future when new values are added to our providers.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, so I suspect there is a bug. We follow Postel's law and allow extra keys in the response, but are strict with the matching on the request. Please raise an issue in the appropriate github repo.

Comment: The like in `like("Sydney")` is redundant by the way. You only need the `eachLike` on the parent hash.

Comment: We think the the problem is occurring due to the following matching rule: `$.body.factories[*].*": { "match": "type" }` We're wondering if Pact NPM should be producing this matching rule or if it is a bug with Pact NPM.

Comment: I agree, this is not expected behaviour. Something doesn't seem right, however. In your tests you specify the `Content-Type` header `application/json`, in the matching rules it has a regex and in the example its `application/vnd.hal+json`. Can you explain this?

Also, the specification version is 3, that is... not possible with JS AFAIK.

Comment: Yep the matching rule: `"$.headers.Content-Type": { "match": "regex", "regex": "application\\/.*json.*" }` ensures that both "application/json" and "application/vnd.hal+json" are both acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you are describing is supported, see https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/tree/master/examples/e2e for an example.

If you were to remove, say the [eligibility](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/master/examples/e2e/test/consumer.spec.js#L71-L73) object and run the tests everything still works.

If you are still having troubles, please raise a defect on the `pact-js` repository and we'll get to the bottom of it.